# How can I create a custom interface in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a project to develop a application to get a direction in Google Maps.
Now, I can draw a direction with GeoPoints (latitude and longitude) in map. But, I want my application can let the user enter locations (from and to location) (1). So, I want to create a custom interface base on available Google Maps' interface (2).

I need your intructions in step (1) and (2).

I'm very grateful for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You just can define a pair of EditText components in the layout instead of filling it with a MapView.

You know that you can paint whatever you want, not only markers, by means of OverlayItems as described in the [own Google](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) tutorial or in [this other tutorial](http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/mapOverlayDemo.html) about using overlays, on top of a MapView.

Comment: After I had drawn a direction with GeoPoints, Google Maps automatically show a detail instruction. On this available form, there are EditText and Browse Button components which let users can choose start and end location. I want to use it, but I need to custom some things (language, text font...)